# Magento sort Categories & subcategory by Name when Display on Site

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sorting

I have below code it will fetch the category as well as subcategory from Magento.

The Problem is that I have around more then 300 `category` and `subcategory`. So I can not change the manually in Magento `Category Management`.

**I need to a sort category based on Name.**

For Example I have attach the Image

### [image: Category listing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I have found the Solutions for this.

Using `ksort()` we can sort the category and we can display the category in sorting order.

```
foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category)
{
   $_categories[$_category->getName()] = $_category;
}
ksort($_categories);
........normaly use our Code.
```

Now you can see the all Main category will be Coming in sorting order form `A-Z`.